# Cache content that application is requesting from another url

Tags: javascript, caching, nginx

How to cache content from gstatic.com in nginx?

Comment: What is the issue here? You have cache directives for enabling cache. You can use those. Please share the work you have done and ask question on specific issues

Comment: The specific issue is that the application deployed nginx is using gstatic.com so basically its showing the content from another website, and I would like to know if anyone had that specific scenario?